# Java background thread: low priorty

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I have a web-app which has a background thread.  This thread, which is a Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor is given tasks that are considered low priority:  I don't care when they get done.  Often the submitted tasks are a type of logging to a remote DB.

I have read many times that one should not change the actual priority of a thread using Thread.setPriority.  That being the case, I don't want my background tasks to interfere with more important tasks of my server.  What strategies can be used?

Here is what I am thinking about:

I am considering putting Thread.sleep(1) or yeild() at the beginning of the run() method of the background tasks.  This would allow other threads to jump ahead if they have something to do at that moment.  But, this seems hackish.  Suggestions?

Comment: You have read many times where? If you know what's what you want to do, do it. It may not have as much effect as you may think, which is probably what your unstated sources are telling you, but if that's what you think you need, you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the executor is single-threaded it can only occupy one core. As long as your server has N cores those background tasks will never take up more than 1/N of the server load, assuming they do not spawn new threads or dispatch to other thread pools on their own.

Alternatively you can schedule *all* tasks (low and high priority) through one thread pool configured with a [priority queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) and decorate each background task so that it has a low priority. I.e. you can move the scheduling from the kernel to userspace.

Comment: I have a single core VPS.

Answer (score 0):

> I am considering putting Thread.sleep(1) or yeild() at the beginning of the run() method of the background tasks. This would allow other threads to jump ahead if they have something to do at that moment. But, this seems hackish. Suggestions?

`thread.yield()` is often a no-op in many thread implementations and putting it or a sleep at the start of the `run()` method will do little or nothing since your background thread hasn't really started running yet.

> I don't want my background tasks to interfere with more important tasks of my server. What strategies can be used?

You are correct that using thread priorities often have little to no effect on the number of cycles the thread will be given.  This depends a lot of your architecture however so I'd certainly try them to see if it helps.  If you are worried about some high performance operation taking cycles away from other more important threads then about your only recourse is to pepper the loops and other key places in your algorithm with `Thread.sleep(...)` calls.  It may be hackish indeed but it can be effective.

The tricky parts is where to put the calls, what millis sleep should be used, etc..  That's going to take some testing and iteration to optimize the placement of the sleeps.  Also, if you are calling 3rd party libraries or something you might not be able to put the sleep calls at the core places anyway.

If it doesn't work or you don't have access to the right pain points then you may have not choice except offloading your background processing to a remote system for processing.